# Set authenticated proxy settings for Geckofx WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, proxy, geckofx

I am trying to set the proxy settings for geckofx browser in wpf application.

```
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.type"] = 1;
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.http"] = address;
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.http_port"] = portNumber;
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.login"] = Username;
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.password"] = Password;
```

To check whether its working or not, i had integrated burp suite.
My settings are :-

```
address  = 127.0.0.1
port     = 8008
username = ""
password = ""
```

For the first request, the request is passing through the burp suite. Then after I am trying to browse in geckofx browser, but those requests are not captured in the burp suite.

As far I Understood.. the application behaves in the following manner

Internet <--> proxy(Burp Suite) <--> GeckoFX Browser // for first request

When trying to browse in GeckoFX browser

Internet <--> GeckoFX Browser // Directly Connecting Internet

Can you guys please provide some example code that helps to pass every request of geckoFX browser through the proxy server(in my example burp suite)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don't forget to also set `network.proxy.ssl` and `network.proxy.ssl_port` or https will bypass the proxy.